# Convert Map to List using SObject field values

Tags: apex, map, list, dynamic, casting

I have a Map of `Financial__c` records, stored like so:

```
Map<Id, Financial__c> idWithParent = new Map<Id, Financial__c>();
```

The `Id` part belongs to a different objects record, like a service or something, pulled from a lookup field on the Financial Record itself. Then we store the entire Financial record the lookup ID was pulled from.

On the individual `Financial__c` records is a `Status` field with one of two values: `Paid` or `New`.

I can cast the `Financial__c` records from a map into a list like so:

```
List<Financial__c> finRecords = idWithParent.values();
```

My question, is can I cast only specific records from the list using that status field, and ignore the rest?

Something like this:

```
List<Financial__c> paidOnly = idWithParent.values().onlyPaidStatusRecords.onlyAddPaidItems()?
```

I dug through the map documentation but am having issues figuring this out. I know I can iterate through the map, but was hoping to eliminate iterating the long way if I can do it quickly doing something like above.

Is this possible? If so, how is it done?

Comment: I believe u r already running a loop to prepare the Map in first place.. y can't u check the status and add only the Financial records with matching status into the map ?

Comment: We're passing the one map into different functions which is then looking within each function for specific things from the map. I would actually have to create several maps and lists in order to accomplish the goal. Passing in one map and then looking for what I want from it seems easier. Or I'm just not designing this well I suppose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out of the box way to do what you want. You have to iterate. You can write some simple filter mechanisms or use a library like [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) to make your life easier. With that library, you can do things like:

```
List<Financial__c> paidOnly = Select.Field.isEqual(Financial__c.Status__c, 'Paid')
    .filter(idWithParent.values());
```

If your just checking simple equality, it's pretty easy to genericize sans library.

```
public static List<SObject> filterIsEqual
    (SObjectField field, Object value, List<SObject> records)
{
    List<SObject> output = new List<SObject>();
    for (SObject record : records)
        if (record.get(field) == value)
            output.add(record);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed to know. I'm a little bummed there isn't currently a simple on line way of doing it. But I won't complain since the solution is still pretty simple and straight forward. Thank you very much for pointing out how to do it! I'll record it in my code journal for future reference.